# When I push a image to Docker Hub... does the image is a "snapshot" of all customizations.. or is created again when you pull/run it?

Tags: docker

Learning Docker here... I have a simple question. I can't figure out the following.

**Today, Alice build and push her custom image** to Docker Hub:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add --update --no-cache mysoftware
```

When Alice build the image, `mysoftware` (say version `1.0`) will be added to the image.

**Next week, Bob pull the image**. In the meanwhile, `mysoftware` has bumped to `1.1` version. Does bob gets the updated version of `mysoftware`... or the `apk add mysoftware` command is "freezed" at the time that Alice build/push the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build your image docker is using sha256 code of base image, so even if tag of your base image (`alpine:latest` in your case) will point on different image - your container will still be using exactly the same image it was using during creation. Only docker build is creating new image, push and pull will only transfer earlier built image.

If you want to update your image you'll have to do `docker build` and `docker push` again

Comment: So... there is no point to specify (for example) apk add mysoftware=1.0 because, at the time of my build, mysoftware is exactly at that version... right?

Comment: @gremo it depends, if you want just to build image now and never touch it again, then yes. But if you want to be able to rebuild you image in couple of month (to get updated alpine image for example) and you need exact version of package installed - then it worth to specify version

Comment: Seems quite logic. Thank you!